# I need to move scroll bar on top and also need to know height value?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriver

How to handle this kind of scroll-bar?How to get value of height: from each div?
I have tried all different kind of java-script function,but it seems nothing works for me.  I need method basically it will tell me scroll bar is present or not?I know the xpath for first one which is 
//div[contains(@style,'position') and contains(@style,'scroll')]" but

### what is the xpath for second div?

---

Comment: <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 18px; top: 29px; height: 498px;">
<div style="width: 18px; height:116841px;"></div>
</div>

Comment: What do you mean by second div? Do you expect another div with same attribute and values?